# Javascript - Iframe load all parent window scripts?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

How do I make an iframe load all parent window's scripts?

I was thinking something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="somethingelse.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <script>
                        for (var i=0;i<window.parent.document.scripts.length;i++){
                            var script = window.parent.document.scripts[i];
                            //now it should append 'script' to document.scripts (this iframe scripts array)
                        }
                    </script>
                </head>
                <body>
                </body>
            </html>
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

PS: I made it as simple as possible. The real code is much bigger.

Comment: The iframe and the root page are both from the same domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
for (var i in window.parent.document.scripts){
    var parentScript = window.parent.document.scripts[i];
    var newScript = document.createElement('script');

    if(parentScript.src)
        newScript.src = parentScript.src;

    if(parentScript.innerHTML)
        newScript.innerHTML = parentScript.innerHTML;

    document.head.appendChild(newScript);
}
```

Comment: Works. For `parentScript.src` does it have to be downloaded again? Or, if it is cached, it will just not be downloaded ? I know that `parentScript.innerHTML` needs no download, but only works for internal scripts.

Comment: @MagisterMundus, the browser will handle the cached "src". The "innerHTML" won't download anything. It is there to completely copy all the scripts that have something to be executed, e.g. `<script>somethingToBeExecuted();</script>`. You can delete this case if you just want to get the scripts that have a source to be included.

Comment: offtopic: Over 1000 views and only one upvote: thats a shame. Thank you for your effort!